# Why is this html, css and javascript not working with iScroll4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, iscroll4

I am building a mobile website. I need the header to be position:fixed (but being mobile that is not supported) so I am using iScroll4 because it seems to be what I am looking for. For some reason I am not able to figure out how to implement it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--includes the iscroll.js file-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<!--header contents-->
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="scroller">
<!--a bunch of html that you probably don't care to see-->
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#header {
    background: #4B92DB;
    border: none;
    height: 175px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
var myScroll;
            function loaded() {
            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
            }

            document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

If you have any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Where's your `loaded()` being called? This (or something like it) might help:

```
<body onload="loaded()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading iScroll4 official page might help you. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Section: Getting started. There are 3 ways to make it work:

1. onDOMContentLoaded event to trigger iscroll
2. onLoad event to trigger
3. inline, place the code below the html bit you want to scroll

All codes are just on the page mentioned.